# Prisma migrate command gets stuck

Tags: postgresql, next.js, prisma, supabase

I am trying to use Prisma with a local instance of Supabase running on docker. I created a very basic model inside `prisma/schema.prisma` file:

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DB_URL")
}

model Post {
  id String @id @default(uuid())
  title String
}
```

I also have the `DB_URL` variable in the .env file:

```
DB_URL="postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:54322/postgres"
```

When I run `npx prisma migrate dev --name init` to create a migration, I get the following message on the console and the process just runs without any result until I break it.

```
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
Datasource "db": PostgreSQL database "postgres", schema "public" at "localhost:54322"
```

Am I missing something? Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but there are a couple of [open bugs on Prisma's git](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues) about migrations. I'd poke around there to see if someone else has this error. I had a similar error that prevented migrations, but mine was a permissions error on Supabase. I left the original DB in place but also created an additional DB and set it as the [shadowDatabaseUrl](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#datasource), and mine started working again.

Comment: Thanks @SeanW
I read about the shadowDatabase which is mentioned in [Supabase documentation](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/integrations/prisma#configuring-the-project-to-use-postgresql) as well, but as far as I understood, it is for when connecting the instance running on the supabase server. So, for the local one it should be fine, but I might be wrong.

Comment: I use supabase for dev and prod servers, so IDK about local. My migrations worked until Prisma v4.7 - my migrations broke in Prisma v4.8 (current is v4.9). I updated to v4.9 and added the shadowdb the other day - it started working again for me. A few people are reporting various reasons for it not working, so I don't know which is affecting your migration.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by using [ShadowDatabaseUrl](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/integrations/prisma#configuring-the-project-to-use-postgresql)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Supabase, then Supabase also needs DIRECT_URL apart from DATABASE_URL

Example:

```js
datasource db {
  provider  = "postgresql"
  url       = env("DATABASE_URL")
  directUrl = env("DIRECT_URL")
}
```

In .env file pass both

```js
DATABASE_URL="postgres://postgres.jwlrudqrfkwjefmuaodb:[password]@aws-0-ap-south-1.pooler.supabase.com:6543/postgres"

DIRECT_URL="postgres://postgres.jwlrudqrfkwjefmuaodb:[password]aws-0-ap-south-1.pooler.supabase.com:5432/postgres"
```